# Unable to get a multi line query executed

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

I have a multi line-command query that I want to execute. The query includes creating temporary tables and returning a table by using them. The code I tried:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", ...);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}else{
    echo "good";
}

$query  = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TT1 AS (Select * from `T1` order by `id` desc);";
$query .= "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TT2 AS (SELECT @n := @n + 1 `id`, `c1`, `c2`, `c3` FROM TT1, (SELECT @n := 0) m );";
$query .= "(Select `id`, `c3` from `TT2` limit 1) union (Select `id`, `c3` from `TT2` where `id`%25=0 ORDER BY `id` asc) union (Select `id`, `c3` from `TT2` where (`id`-1)%25=0 ORDER BY `id` asc) union (Select `id`, `c3` from `TT2` order by `id` desc limit 1) order by `c3` desc;";


/* execute multi query */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }else{
            echo "bad2";
        }
        /* print divider */
        if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }else{
            echo "bad3";
        }
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}else{
    echo "bad1";
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

I am dealing with:

1. The program does not do well with handling temporary tables,
2. The program exits beacuse of error exactly after parsing the first query,
3. I dont know how to actually get the info of the last query.

I should mention that the queries work exactly as intentioned in phpMyAdmin console.

**Edit**

As for debugging I added some echoes to find the flow of the program.
The program outputs:

```
goodbad1
```

Comment: Can you share more details, like the full and exact error message, and your debugging attempts?

Comment: @NicoHaase Added them as edit.

Comment: You have accidently added your password into the question. Please change it.

Comment: As for debugging, you should always have error reporting enabled. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439) If you are on newest PHP release then you should see all potential errors

Comment: Please share the **errors** you are facing, not any output you've generated on your own

Comment: @NicoHaase The output is there. I am not sure why it's like that, but that is irrelevant actually IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split it up into 3 separate queries and execute it one after another. Never use `multi_query()`!

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", ...);
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset

$query = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TT1 AS (Select * from `T1` order by `id` desc);";
$mysqli->query($query);

$query = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TT2 AS (SELECT @n := @n + 1 `id`, `c1`, `c2`, `c3` FROM TT1, (SELECT @n := 0) m );";
$mysqli->query($query);

$query = "(Select `id`, `c3` from `TT2` limit 1) union (Select `id`, `c3` from `TT2` where `id`%25=0 ORDER BY `id` asc) union (Select `id`, `c3` from `TT2` where (`id`-1)%25=0 ORDER BY `id` asc) union (Select `id`, `c3` from `TT2` order by `id` desc limit 1) order by `c3` desc;";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

foreach ($result as $row) {
    // Do something
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['c3'];
}
```

Comment: I am an amateur in php. Given that the table has two columns how do I get the table?

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: Ok thank you I figured it out with `echo $row["id"]." ".$row["c3"]."<br>";` Surely I will check it out.